# Strip styles option in Rich Text field?

Tags: redactor, richtext

Is there a way to add a button to remove the current styles inside of a Rich Text field? I know there are options for customizing the toolbar, but I haven't found anything about removing styles. Any ideas?

Comment: or reset it to normal under formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this that works well. Reverts to p tags or normal text:

https://bitbucket.org/kreisvierdigital/redactorremoveformat